# Displays won't stay off when I put them to sleep

Tags: macos, display

when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Eject</kbd> the displays go blank for a second, then they turn on again.
There's no way I can get them off permanently.
I also don't want the computer to sleep as I leave it downloading over night.
I have a MacBook with an external monitor attached.

Comment: As I understand you ask 2 different question, you can't permanently turn off your screen and let your macbook download your file during night?

Comment: May be I wasn't clear enough. What I want is to put the displays to sleep and that they stay off, which doesn't happen.

Comment: Newer Macbook Pros use Ctrl+Shift + Power, because they lack an Eject button. There is also the option of using a "Hot Corner" for the same effect. This problem still exists. Haven't tried power cycling to reset to SMC yet... I wonder if that really would solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this can be due to the System Management Controller.  Try [resetting the SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US) and see if that helps

Comment: Great, tried it and worked. I hope it keeps working. Thanks!